# How to call an individual method from another python module which has got a main function in it

Tags: python, unit-testing, methods, program-entry-point

I'm having a python module eg: myexample.py with the below contents.

```
import os, sys
class nw_clss():
    def new_func():
        /*some statements*/

def main():

main(some arguments)
```

Now am writing a unittest framework where I would need to call some individual functions in the myexample.py. 
However, since there is a main method inside the myexample.py, whenever am trying to call an individual function, the framework is actually calling the main method and executing all methods available in myexample.py

Is there any possible to override this and just call the individual methods.

Thanks,
Arjun

Comment: If you `import myexample as me`, cant you just do `x=me.nw_class(), x.new_func()`?

Comment: This is again giving the same error. The main method is getting invoked instead of the     x.new_function()

Comment: Use the `if __name__ == '__main__':` from below.

Comment: Thanks a lot Henry, this worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the purpose of

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

which you might have seen from time to time.

when you run a module directly, its `__name__` variable will be `'__main__'`, but it will be different if imported by another module, so code in a block like this will only execute when that module is run directly.

EDIT: to clarify, what you want to have is

```
import os, sys
class nw_clss():
    def new_func():
        /*some statements*/

def main():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main_':
    main(some arguments)
```

EDIT 2: from the comments

in your unittest module if you only want to test 1 part of the module (eg the class) you can import only that:

```
from myexample import nw_clss
```

which won't run the whole module. It's less good that writing code with good practice, but if for some reason whoever wrote that original code won't let you then I guess that is what you have to do.

Comment: ok. But I don't have an option to change the main(). This is because, the main () is being referred by another java code.

So the only option I have is to individually call the methods and execute it for unit testing.

Comment: @Arjun I don't understand what you mean by that, how is your java code referring this python module? What is the exact problem caused by making my suggested change?

Comment: the python module myexample.py is actually being referred by a piece of java code for some functionality. so unfortunately I don't have the liberty to change any piece of code in myexample.py. 

All I can change is the way the unit test cases are run. In my unittest case, I'm instantiating an object of myexample.py module class  - nw_clss and trying to invoke a particular function. This way of calling the methods is failing with the error message saying the main is expecting 9 arguments and am passing only 4 or 5 arguments which is specific to the particular function.

Comment: @Arjun do you mean that this java code is calling myexample.py? I don't really know how that would work but I would have assumed that it meant that the java would send a command to the shell to run "python myexample.py". If that is the case then my change wouldn't work. It's also very standard good practice, so it should be done either way.

Comment: @Arjun but you can also (I think) just import the class, but using `from myexample import nw_clss` to test it - I don't think that calls the `main()` function.

Comment: The way of calling 
    from myexample import nw_clss 
is not working. Every time we try to call the 
    object of nw_class.new_func() 
it is calling the main function and throwing error.

Comment: @Arjun that is quite clearly a problem with either the `main()` function or the  `.new_func()` method, which was not your question - i thought you wanted to know how to import it, now you're asking me why code you haven't posted doesn't work, which I can't possibly know.